# Not getting props from child component in Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I want to get props from Redux in the child component. But {this.props} is empty object. I am using react-redux connect to get the props. It is working in parent component and we can pass to child component to get the props but I need to get from child component

## Login

````
```import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Test } from './Test'

export default class Login extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Test hi=""/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}```
````

## Test

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

export class Test extends Component {
    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        return (
            <div>
                vddfff
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({

})

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        selectedData: (val) => {
            console.log("object")
        }
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Test)
```

Comment: Because you missed `constructor(props) { super() }`. There are a good explanation about it https://overreacted.io/why-do-we-write-super-props/

Comment: You props do nothing with redux.

Comment: @demkovych I added constructer. but still the same. One more thing I can see this.props.hi from parent to child but not this.props.selectedData

Comment: just use `const mapDispatchToProps = {
  selectedData: selectedDataAction
};` where `selectedDataAction` is your action (from redux)

Comment: You might want to use `dispatch` in the body of `selectedData` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that you are trying to use the Test component you wrote instead of the Higher order component which is being returned by the `connect()` from `react-redux`
You don't need to export the `Test` class.

In login.js file, use

`import Test from './Test'`

instead of

`import {Test} from './Test'`

See it in action here.
https://codesandbox.io/s/sample-test-app-q5srf

Answer (score 0):

You used the wrong component. In login you need to import:

```
import Test from './Test'
```

You imported Test wich is not connected to redux (that pushes the redux props).